# Using greenbrown package with Landsat data

Tags: r, time-series, raster, r-raster, landsat

I have been trying to use the 'PhenologyRaster' function of the `greenbrown` package to model the growing season of my study area. However, everytime I run the function, I get empty outputs (e.g. the SOS.2016 layer will show as NA). My question is the following: am I having issues because I am running the function on one single year of data, or because Landsat time series are somewhat irregular (i.e. frequency of ~30 scenes per year)?

I am using the following piece of code to run the PhenologyRatser function:

```
PhenoTest = PhenologyRaster(landsat2016,start=c(2016,1,3),end=c(2016,12,20),freq=24,approach="Deriv",min.mean=-0.5,tsgf='TSGFspline',interpolate=TRUE)
```

The function is applied on a raster stack with the following characteristics:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 526, 591, 310866, 18  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 604965, 622695, 4208175, 4223955  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : X2016.01.03, X2016.01.19, X2016.02.04, X2016.03.07, X2016.03.23, X2016.04.24, X2016.05.10, X2016.05.26, X2016.06.27, X2016.07.13, X2016.07.29, X2016.08.14, X2016.08.30, X2016.09.15, X2016.10.01, ... 
min values  :     -0.1964,          NA,     -0.5382,          NA,     -0.4696,     -0.2197,     -0.2803,     -0.4274,     -0.4827,     -0.2631,     -0.5256,     -0.4856,     -0.5631,     -0.3204,     -0.5512, ... 
max values  :      0.1714,          NA,      0.2425,          NA,      0.2061,      0.5173,      0.4583,      0.2470,      0.3629,      0.5165,      0.2981,      0.2802,      1.6199,      0.5016,      0.3007, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. What I did was that I created a dummy series for three years and then the data were successfully run.

```
b.1 <- brick(r.1, r.2, r.3, r.4, r.5, r.6, r.7, r.8, r.9, r.10, r.11, r.12)
b.2 <- stack(b.2, b.2, b.2)
pheno.test <- PhenologyRaster(b.2, start=c(2016,1), freq=12, approach="White", 
                              tsgf="TSGFspline", interpolate=T)
```

Comment: I would also advise that you should remove negative values from the data, as the may not represent the greenness.
You can initially remove the negative values from rasters 

e.g.,

values (r.1) [values(r.1)<0 ] = NA